# Angular async pipe inside ngFor returns null

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, angularfire, ngfor

I have the following code:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories | async">
  {{ events | async | json }}
</ng-container>



this.categories = this.db
  .collection('categories')
  .valueChanges();

this.events = this.categories
  .pipe(switchMap((categories: { category: EventCategory }[]) => categories))
  .pipe(mergeMap((category: { category: EventCategory }) => {
    return this.db
      .collection('events')
      .doc(category.category)
      .collection('items', ref => ref
        .where('endTime', '>=', +new Date()))
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(map((events: Event[]) => events.map(mapToDate)))
      .pipe(map((events: Event[]) => ({ [category.category]: events })));
  }))
  .pipe(scan((acc: any, curr: { events: Event[] }) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {}))
  .pipe(debounceTime(100));
```

The result is `null` for events for each category.
The final goal is:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories | async">
  {{ (events | async)[category.category] | json }}
</ng-container>
```

This works as expected though:

```
  {{ events | async | json }}
```

Any idea why the subscription to events returns null inside the subscription of categories ?

Comment: Is there something in your observable ? Have you seen it ? Also provide a [mcve] so that we can see the issue in real time.

Comment: Yep both observable aren't empty and it works as expected when subscribed using: `{{ obs | async | json}}`.

Comment: And if you put it outside of your loop, does it work ?

Comment: Yes:
`{{ events | async | json}}` works as expected
`{{ categories | async | json}}` works as expected.
`<ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories | async">
  {{ category | json }}
</ng-container>` works as expected

Comment: Have you tried `{{ (events | async)?[category.category] | json }}` ?

Comment: Elvis operator can't be used with property access using square brackets I think.
This works though:
`{{ (events | async)?.clubbing | json }}`

Answer (score 0):

For some reason this works:

```
this.events = this.db
  .collection('categories')
  .valueChanges()
  .pipe(switchMap((categories: { category: EventCategory }[]) => categories))
  .pipe(mergeMap((category: { category: EventCategory }) => {
    return this.db
      .collection('events')
      .doc(category.category)
      .collection('items', ref => ref
        .where('endTime', '>=', +new Date()))
      .valueChanges()
      .pipe(map((events: Event[]) => events.map(mapToDate)))
      .pipe(map((events: Event[]) => ({ [category.category]: events })));
  }))
  .pipe(scan((acc: any, curr: { events: Event[] }) => ({ ...acc, ...curr }), {}))
  .pipe(debounceTime(100))
  .pipe(startWith({}));
```

(The difference is that I don't use categories observable as the initial source but query again the categories collection, added startWith operator since I can't use elvis operator to avoid null error at the beginning).